# Contents are not loading properly in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, web-hosting

I bought WordPress theme I uploaded it to the server and I register a domain on GoDaddy .com and added nameserver of an actual server on which my WordPress site is hosted. I have almost done with development and published it. when I went to the browser I entered my domain some contents are not properly got loaded and when I have inspected the content I got following error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://waev.in/wp/wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/extensions/builder/static/css/frontend-grid.css?ver=1.2.5. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sonalvivek.in' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> Font from origin 'http://waev.in' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sonalvivek.in' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Not really clear what exact problem you're facing, on which site. Looks like the site sonalvivek.in is trying to access some resource (media?) from the site waev.in, which is getting blocked. If you explain the problem in more detail, I can investigate further and then try to help.